# as.Date returns NA

Tags: r, datetime

the folowing code returns NA

```
as.Date("Thr Jan 15 2015 07:06:04", format = "%a %b %d %Y %T")
```

already tried to set the system locale as described in `?as.Date`

```
## read in date info in format 'ddmmmyyyy'
## This will give NA(s) in some locales; setting the C locale
## as in the commented lines will overcome this on most systems.
## lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
x <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
z <- as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
## Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
```

Comment: `weekdays(Sys.Date()+1:7, abbreviate=TRUE)` ... on my system its 'Thu'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The abbreviation for Thursday is `Thu`.  So, probably this should work

```
as.Date('Thu Jan 15 2015 07:06:04', format= '%a %b %d %Y %T')
# [1] "2015-01-15"
```

If there are `typos` in the string, then remove the weekday part using `sub`

```
as.Date(sub('[^ ]+ ', '', str1), format= '%b %d %Y %T')
#[1] "2015-01-15"
```

Comment: it is not a typo in the string, as Thr can also be used for Thursday. The sensor that generate the data uses this

Comment: @tetra I think it is based on `abbreviated weekday in the current locale` I get, `format(Sys.Date()+0:6, '%a')#[1] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"`

Comment: I to get `format(Sys.Date()+0:6, '%a')
[1] "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun" "Mon"` it is an issue with the sensor generating the data. But your answer worked so thanks

Comment: @tetra It may depend on where you are living.